# Golang ReverseProxy per host

Tags: http, go, reverse-proxy, go-http

I am trying to implement a Reverse Proxy in Go that proxies traffic to different hosts based on some tenant embedded in the URL. The implementation looks like this:

```golang
type Offloader struct {
    tenantHostMap   map[string]string                   // Map a tenant to its host:port
    tenantProxyMap  map[string](*httputil.ReverseProxy) // Map a tenant to its reverse proxy
}

func (o *Offloader) OnCreate() {

    // Tenants Map
    o.tenantHostMap = make(map[string]string)
    o.tenantProxyMap = make(map[string]*httputil.ReverseProxy)
    o.PopulateTenantHostMap()

    // Rx
    http.HandleFunc("/", o.ServeHTTP)
    go http.ListenAndServe(":5555", nil)

}

// ServeHTTP is the callback that is called each time a Http Request is received.
func (o *Offloader) ServeHTTP(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    incomingUrl := req.URL.RequestURI()
    tenant := o.GetTenantFromUrl(incomingUrl)

    if proxy, ok := o.tenantProxyMap[tenant]; ok {
        proxy.ServeHTTP(w, req)
    }

    if remoteHostAddr, ok := o.tenantHostMap[tenant]; ok {
        remoteUrl, err := url.Parse(fmt.Sprintf("http://%s", remoteHostAddr))
        if err != nil {
            return
        }
        proxy := httputil.NewSingleHostReverseProxy(remoteUrl)
        o.tenantProxyMap[tenant] = proxy
        proxy.ServeHTTP(w, req) // non blocking

    } else {
        panic("Unknown Tenant")
    }
}
```

When receiving a new HTTP request, I get the tenant from the URL. If this is the first time I am seeing this tenant I create a new ReverseProxy, otherwise I try to use the one I created before and stored in the `tenantProxyMap`.

When I test this, I get the following error:

```
2022/04/05 12:31:01 http: proxy error: readfrom tcp ****: http: invalid Read on closed Body
2022/04/05 12:31:01 http: superfluous response.WriteHeader call from net/http/httputil.(*ReverseProxy).defaultErrorHandler (reverseproxy.go:190)
```

If I create a new Reverse Proxy for each request rather than reusing the same proxy, the error doesn't happen.

I thought the proxy is per host and not per request (as the name suggests), so I am wondering why this error happens?

I know I need to protect the maps from concurrent reads/writes however that is irrelevant at the moment.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that in the scenario where a previous proxy already existed, you first pass the request on to that - and then still recreate the proxy, and again pass the request. In other words: you are making two proxied requests for each incoming request, when the tentantProxyMap is already populated for that tenant.

The `ReverseProxy` implementation closes the `req.Body`, so the second time you pass the request on to the proxy, it attempts reading from an already closed body. You're seeing the `http: invalid Read on closed Body` error as a result.

What you should try is to return after proxying the request, e.g. by adding a `return`:

```
if proxy, ok := o.tenantProxyMap[tenant]; ok {
    proxy.ServeHTTP(w, req)
    return
}
```

Comment: I can't believe I get paid to code and I missed that. Thanks